# Powershell script for purging files as per creation year

Tags: powershell

I wrote a powershell script which will iterate through three different path and get list of files that are less then 7 years and delete them from current timestamp.
I am getting creation year of file and if am able to recursively iterate through all those three path.
Problem is out of 3, two paths have too many folders and files due to which when script is in loop it shows memory exception. Also I will not be able to set maxmemorypershellMB, since I don't have access.

Anything else that I can do this to avoid memory exception
this is piece of code below:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "$path"  –Recurse -file    
for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
    $outfile = $files[$i].FullName                                #file name
    $FileDate = (Get-ChildItem $outfile).CreationTime                  #get creation date of file
    $creationYear = $FileDate.Year
    $creationMonth =$FileDate.Month                                     #get only year out of creation date

    If( $creationYear -lt $purgeYear ){
    If (Test-Path $outfile){                                           #check if file exist then only proceed

        $text=[string]$creationYear+" "+$outfile 
        $text >> 'listOfFilesToBeDeleted_PROD.txt'                          #this will get list of files to be deleted
         #remove-item $outfile 
            }
    }
```

}

Comment: You can split `Get-ChildItem "$path"  -Recurse -file ` by first level folders, this way your `$files` will always have less members than full set, and its previous set will be discarded and GC'd, allowing you to parse more files per path.

Comment: i am new to powershell don't know how to restrict them to one level

Comment: also the first level have too many directories and each directory contains too many files. Same script is working fine on local and QA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to filter the the files using [where-object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423) instead of a for loop:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddYears(-7)
$path = "c:\"
$outfile = "c:\test.txt"

Get-ChildItem -Path "$path" -Recurse -file |
     Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | 
     foreach { '{0} {1}' -f $_.CreationTime, $_.FullName |
     Out-File -FilePath $outfile -Append }
```

Solution for your comment:

```
# retrieve all affected files and select the fullname and the creationtime
$affectedFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "$path" -Recurse -file |
 Where-Object { $_.CreationTime.Year -lt $purgeYear } | 
  select FullName, CreationTime

 foreach ($file in $affectedFiles)
 {
    # write the file to listOfFilesToBeDeleted
    '{0} {1}' -f $file.CreationTime.Year, $file.FullName | 
         Out-File -FilePath listOfFilesToBeDeleted.txt -Append

    # delete the file
    Remove-Item -Path $file.FullName -Force
 }
```

Comment: this is working for me i modified it according to creation year. But here how do I Delete "$_.FullName"  which is returning name file i want it to be deleted after all condition are satisfied.
remove-item $_.FullName  will ths work after append

Comment: You can write the foreach like this: foreach { rm $_.FullName -force; '{0} {1}' -f $_.CreationTime, $_.FullName

Comment: Get-ChildItem -Path "$path" -Recurse -file |
     Where-Object { $_.CreationTime.Year -lt $purgeYear} | 
     foreach { '{0} {1}' -f $_.CreationTime.Year, $_.FullName |
     Out-File -FilePath listOfFilesToBeDeleted.txt  -Append }

Heere $purgeyear is :
$a = Get-Date
$purgeYear = $a.Year-7

I want list also as well as delete them after I get list

Comment: thanks a lot the previous piece of code I am currently running, it is running without any issues. Will add delete this delete feature later
thank you very much again